# Why technologies I'm not using is on my AWS server

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've recently deployed ubuntu 20.04 ec2 AWS server and install wordpress manually. I've just download apache2, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, PHP while setup. However, when I inspect using wappalyzer it shows some technologies I've not installed. I'm only using jquery, tag manager Cloudflare other than above and no any plugin installed. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you're using CloudFlare then some of these technologies are actually from the CDN (such as NGINX for the proxy).

Wordpress also uses a lot of these dependencies natively and are included in its own bundled javascript files. Wappalyzer knows that because you're using Wordpress that some of those libraries are also running, even if it cannot see them loaded (i.e. TinyMCE for the backend).

For any other dependencies for frontend libraries these have should be available to see in your Network tab. They are likely being included by third party libraries either as part of Wordpress, a plugin or the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks for your response but why Sitefinity is there and also MailChimp. I'm not using MailChimp.

Comment: MailChimp will be wordpress most likely based on assumptions. Not sure for Sitefinity why. Some of these are simply because other people who run stacks (such as Wordpress) almost always use another library. It will only be able to scan network resources (i.e. requests with responses and headers) to determine technologies used. If nothing loads sitefinity then they're making an assumption.